# why are all the opengl enums hexadecimal?

Tags: java, opengl, enums, hex

why are all the opengl enums hexidecimal?

example:

```
GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS = 0x8B4A
```

The enums are used as parameters in GL functions. So my question is, why are all the parameters hexidecimal ?

Comment: What does it matter? It's a number; whether it's in hex, decimal, octal, or binary, it's the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure in this case, but in cases where it matters which bits are set, using hexadecimal is easier to figure out which bits are set.